# Make fake multilanguage subfolders for website

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, multilingual

I'd like to know if it is possible to make fake subfolders for my multilanguage website, right now I use this code to switch between the two languages I have (Italian and English)

```
<?php
session_start();

$langs = [ "en", "it" ];

$current_lang = "en";

if (isset($_GET["lang"]))
{
    $lang = $_GET["lang"];
    if (in_array($lang, $langs, true))
        $current_lang = $lang;
    
}
elseif (!isset($_SESSION["lang"]))
{
    
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]))
    {
        $acceptLang = $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"];
        if (strlen($acceptLang) > 2)
        {
            $acceptLang = strtolower(substr($acceptLang, 0, 2));
            if (in_array($acceptLang, $langs, true))
                $current_lang = $acceptLang;
        }
    }
}
else
    $current_lang = $_SESSION["lang"];

$_SESSION["lang"] = $current_lang;


require_once "languages/$current_lang.php";
?>
```

So whenever I want to switch language I add to the end of the URL  ?lang=neededLanguage.php

I also use these rewrite rules to hide the .php

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

This is what I have to do to switch language right now:
https://example.com/?lang=en
https://example.com/blog?lang=en

I'd like to know if it's possible to make the previous two URLs look something like these:
https://example.com/en/
https://example.com/en/blog

Also the blog part of the URL is a .php file